# Unable to use password less login with ssh

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh, ssh-keys

I am using SSH for my vm and want to login as another user name using password less login method. I have created the private/public keys with following command.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

but when i try to login without password, i am getting the following stack.

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/systest/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.2.67 [192.168.2.67] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/systest/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/systest/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/systest/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '192.168.2.67' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/systest/.ssh/known_hosts:18
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/systest/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/systest/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/systest/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

can any one kindly tell me what is the problem. I am new to this.

I have added the public key with this command

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Comment: It sounds like you haven't added you public key to the VM machine yet? Is that correct?

Comment: @isomarcte I have append the public key to authorized_keys file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to copy you public key to the remote host.

In your home directory on the local machine, that is the machine on which you ran `ssh-keygen`. Look inside the `.ssh` folder. There you will see these two files.

```
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
```

The file `id_rsa` is your private key **(don't let anyone ever have access to this file, ever**), and the file `id_rsa.pub` is your public key.

You need to copy the contents of `id_rsa.pub`, your public key, into the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the remote server.

This can be done quickly, if password authentication is enabled, with the `ssh-copy-id` command

```
ssh-copy-id me@somehost
```

After doing this you may disable password authentication in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on the remote host.

Comment: thanks for response, I have already added the contents to authorized_keys

Comment: i used cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys' to copy the key.

Comment: Hmmm.. that should do it. Can you try the `ssh-copy-id` command? Can you post back, if that command succeeds, and what happens if you try to login after running that command?

Comment: after using ssh-copy-id: /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found

Comment: This is while you are running the `ssh-copy-id` command? That is strange, are you sure you are logged in as the correct user then?

It should have found identities your home folder. What does `ls ~/.ssh/` output from that shell?

Comment: ssh-copy-id worked for me as well (where the cat over ssh did not).

Answer (score 0):

If you have already set the proper permissions for the .ssh folder and authorized_keys file, then you might check the owner and group of your home folder.

e.g. `$ ll /home
drwxr-xr-x 3 <your user id> <your goup> 4096 Jul 16  2015 <your user home folder>/`

If the user and group are wrong, and you have sudo access, change the owner and group.

e.g. `$ sudo chown -R <your user id>:<your goup> /home/<your user home folder>`